How to prevent user from executing PHP script multiple times within few seconds?
I want to be able to run php script and then it should check itself to make sure X number of seconds have passed before it can run again. I am not talking about halting it's execution for x number of seconds using sleep() procedure.
For instance, a user clicks on a link to execute a PHP script. That php script shouldn't be allowed to run again until it has finished its execution and/or x number of seconds have passed, even if the user clicks the link again real quick like within a second.
I was thinking of creating a time difference flag and check it every time PHP script is called, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.
php file
//For the first time, it will skip over this block of code, because $timediff is not initialized yet.
if (isset($timediff))
{
   if ((microseconds(true) - $timediff)<10) {
      exit();
}
...
$timediff = microseconds(true);
...

But this doesn't work for me.
Any hints or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

You need to store the last execution time and whether the script is running somewhere, in a lock file or database.

How is that PHP script getting executed? Is it just a link like /yourserver/path/foo.php? In which case every execution is independent so your $timediff is not shared across runs. "because $timediff is not initialized yet" will always be true.

oh okay. Can I store it in a session?

Yes you can store it in a session -- if you want a separate limit to apply to each user. If user1 clicks and then user2 immediately clicks, should it run or no?

but each user will have his or her own unique session. right? execution of this php script will be based on user's session.

A normal session will only really work if the user allows you to store a cookie. Robots, for instance, often don't.

Browser sessions may not be the same as user sessions.  A single user may have multiple browser instances running, so bear that in mind if it's important to what you're trying to do

So, here is the situation. I have a webpage with php script links that allow a user to download PDF file when he or she clicks on the link, but as we found recently there is a chance that the user can repeatedly click the link(s) overloading the system and locking up our webserver. It has happened and I am trying to prevent this from happening.

Does the user have to authenticate to get to the page with the link? Or is it publicly accessible to the whole internet?

remove the hyperlink (with JS) or change it's attributes when clicked. To click again would require page reload?

The user doesn't have to authenticate but is asked to provide their name, email address and their phone number. Finally, the user is asked to verify that they are not robot using google's recaptcha just once or the first time. If they fail to, script blocks them from downloading. However, once the user successfully gets passed this, they are allowed to click on the links as much as they want.

Is the "overloading the system" coming from the actual download bandwidth usage? Or is it that you're generating the PDF dynamically and it's computationally expensive to do so?

@AlexHowansky All downloadable PDF files are already stored in the webserver; not being dynamically created. it is not so much to do with bandwidth but rather the fact that there are too many requests for files and PDF files as you know are generally large in size, even though I compressed it to easily and quickly download these PDF FILES. Think of it like DDOS attack.

I assume the URLs to the PDFs are not dynamic? In other words, if the URL is sent to someone else they don't have to go through the process of providing name, email address, phone number, and do the Google ReCaptcha. Right? You could use dynamic URL's that require the user to have a session and complete all the requirements mentioned above. I doubt that it will be such a normal user who is DDOSing your server. It's certainly possible for a robot to imitate such an user, but rather unlikely. Also, only allowing one download could impact the usability of your service.

@KIKOSoftware Actually, you are partially correct. The links to PDFs are NOT dynamic. However, the direct links to the file is HIDDEN through php script. The script is only given the file name and only the script knows the exact location. It then, streams the file to the user's browser or client. As far as new user or browser, they have to go through process of providing all those information and ReCaptcha. In fact, once you close your browser, you will be asked to give those information and do ReCaptcha again.

OK, so the public links to the PDFs, those PHP scripts, are dynamic. Surely you placed the actual PDFs outside the web root? And you made sure, that your assumptions, that an user has to provide all the information, is correct? Anyway, my point about impacting usability if you restrict users to one download is important. If you implement something like this, it should be obvious to the user that the link cannot be used twice, and also what they should do if, for whatever reason, they want to download the PDF again.

A simple search for "php limit per second" turns up many answers here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720230/php-antiflood-how-to-limit-2-requests-per-second, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852796/php-limit-request-per-second, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579840/how-do-i-observe-a-rate-limit-in-php, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475376/how-to-limit-the-number-of-user-requests-made-within-a-minute, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446824/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-connections-per-second-made-to-server-in-get-php5, ...

What you're really doing is rate limiting, and a search for the more accurate terms "php rate limit" turns up more answers, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257678/php-rate-limiting-client

This question is similar to: PHP rate limiting client. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
